# How to transfer sort params in cookies?

Tags: yii2

In controller I have got a variable which contains sort params. In view I have got a gridview which perfect sorts and even when I reload page the sorted column keeps sorted. But I also have got some filters and submit button for extending my select from db and when I press this button the sorted column resets to default. I want to keep it and try to use cookies, but it doesn't help.

```
if ($List->sort->attributes)
        {
            Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
                'name' => 'sort',
                'value' => $List->sort->attributes,
            ]));
        }
```

Selected column resets after submit anyway. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

By default GridView gets sorting parameters from url, like this `?sort=-status` which means `desc` sorting by `status`. As follows from your question You have some form on your view which should perform some additional data filtering, like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="filter">
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

if so, then You just need to preserve sorting parameters in url for your form action, for example

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= \Yii::$app->request->getUrl() ?>">
```

or if You use ActiveForm:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'method' => 'POST',
    'action' => \Yii::$app->request->getUrl(),
]);
```

If You want to use cookies, then You should manually get sorting attributes in Your controller and apply them to the query which You pass to your dataProvider (or to the `sorter` config).

Draw Your attention that here is another common way to add filtering in GridView -- **`filterModel`** property.

Form [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$filterModel-detail):

> The model that keeps the user-entered filter data. When this property
>   is set, the grid view will enable column-based filtering. Each data
>   column by default will display a text field at the top that users can
>   fill in to filter the data.
>
> Note that in order to show an input field for filtering, a column must
>   have its yii\grid\DataColumn::$attribute property set and the
>   attribute should be active in the current scenario of $filterModel or
>   have yii\grid\DataColumn::$filter set as the HTML code for the input
>   field.
>
> When this property is not set (null) the filtering feature is
>   disabled.